# Control a raw socket from a web interface

Tags: sockets, tomcat, webserver, jetty

I have an microprocessor which I can control through a raw tcp socket. I can control the device through a desktop application, but I now want to be able to control it via the web. I've done lots of reading but I'm struggling to find the best method to do this. So far it seems creating a socket server in a webserver such as Tomcat or Jetty is the best option. When the user clicks a button the command is then sent to the micro processor. Is this a viable approach or are there better methods?

It is important that the system is very responsive, in other words, when the user clicks a button on the web page, the microprocessor must receive it as soon possible.

Answer (score 0):

imo...separate your concerns

first write the code that implements the behavior you want with the microprocessor in such a way it is generally useful, and then plug on whatever sort of controller you want, be it web page, junit test, command line interface, whatever.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but I already have the behavior I want with the microprocessor. It receives simple commands via the tcp socket that it connects to. The socket server is currently a .Net program. Now, instead of using the .net program, I rather want to use a website, so the web server must host the website and also be the socket server. Does this make sense?

Comment: sure, I would just use an embedded instance of jetty then as a starting point, something like this: http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/example-jetty-embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/OneServletContext.java

Comment: Can I create a socket server using embedded Jetty? The microprocessor must be the client so that I don't run into any firewall issues. I good with desktop applications but very new to web applications.

Comment: sure, but still I would just write a plain ole java class that interacts with your microprocessor however you want, opening socket or whatever internally, and then just expose that to the webapp in some way, perhaps via REST or whatever...but you could just write all that in a servlet and deploy that into jetty, see the example I pasted for that, the HelloServlet is ultimately what you would be adding your code into.